# Removing request validation from page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page that is part of a CMS control panel where the user can fill certain textboxes with javascipt code to be saved in a database. The callbacks are being blocked by the server with the following exception:

> Exception message: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtMenuAdsenseCode="

I am not exactly sure why the server is complaining about a textbox value when I am not doing a full postback, but is there any way to turn this off? I put `ValidateRequest="false"` in the page and this in the `web.config`:

```
  <location path="~/Admin/Settings.aspx">
      <system.web>
        <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
      </system.web>
    </location>
```

But it is still throwing the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try serializing the contents of the textbox code to Base64 using Javascript, and then decode from Base64 in your code-behind.

I usually use an extension method such as this:

```
public static string DecodeFrom64(this string encodedData)
{
    var data = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);
    string result = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I was able to remove validation by doing `/Admin/Settings.aspx` instead. Your solution can work too though!